# how to deal with hierarchical domain objects?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

:-) I'm creating a model that is hierarchical in its nature.

For example, an object of class Foo is useless when it's alone and it makes sense (it's useful for actual usage) only if placed in its context of Foo[] (like Foo > Foo > Foo > Foo > **Foo**)

Therefore most of its mapper's fetch-methods should return an array of Foo, that represents its hierarchical structure. Also, there would be also fetch-methods that return sets of this structures, like:

```
$data[0] = array(new Foo, new Foo, new Foo, new Foo);
$data[1] = array(new Foo, new Foo, new Foo, new Foo);
```

I will also have methods that fetch one single Foo only, but they will be mostly used for "under the hood" tasks, like writing data to a database.

Plus, those objects are related together in many ways: for example, if I update one of those Foo's, more than likely I will have to update all the Foo's that are ancestors/descendant of it.

What would you do with this kind of design? Am I mixing up things?

Thanks a lot in advance!! I Hope to have been clear!

Comment: I don't understand very good how your Foo-structure looks like... Are all elements Foo (Foos contain Foos)? Is it kind of tree-structure? Maybe Folder-file structure? Could you please provide a concrete example of this structure?

Comment: Foo contains one or zero Foo, it is a folder-file like structure! but there's no concrete example, I'm just playing with OOP.

Comment: Sorry, but still unclear. You say "Foo contains one or zero Foo". This means that it's a flat sequence of Foos?! Do you maybe meant that a Foo can have 0 or 1 parent Foo? It would be nice if you could draw a simple example, how you imagine it.

Comment: I would see it as specific variation on "collection" concept. Only in this case you are dealing with a `Tree`. Mapper interacts with this `Tree` instance (stores data from it of fetches data into it). In that case you only need to look up *"How to populate tree structures"*.